# Dynamic Page Fixed header and footer disappears and moves on android/iphone

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

As per the title. The header and footer stay fixed on the desktop but on mobile browsers(chrome, safari, phonegap webview) the header and footer are nowhere to be seen once scrolled to the middle of the page.

Occasionally they will reappear if I double tap on the screen somewhere.

I'm create the page dynamically using this code:

```
$j.mobile.pageContainer.append('<div data-role="page" id="' + id + '" class="formswidget"><div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" data-id="portalHeader"><a href="jsmenu.html" data-icon="home">Home</a><a data-icon="gear" href="settings.html">Settings</a><h1 id="formsheader">Forms</h1></div> <!-- header div --><div id="insertiondiv" data-role="content"></div><!-- content div --><div data-role="footer" id="formsfooter" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" class="ui-body-a"><div data-role="navbar"><ul><li id="backbutton"><a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a></li><li id="savebutton"><a href="#">Save</a></li><li id="submitbutton"><a href="#">Submit</a></li></ul></div><!--navbardiv--></div><!--footerdiv--></div><!--pagediv-->');
```

As you can see from this overly long dynamic page. I have both

```
data-tap-toggle="false"
data-position="fixed"
```

set on both the header and the footer.

It seems that when I use static external pages, I don't encounter this issue. But on dynamically generated and appended pages, the issue is present.

I feel like I have tried everything that I've seen decremented on SO and other sites but nothing works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

SEE EDIT

Solved it.

After appending the html I was instantiating the page with

```
$j("#dynamicpageid").page()
```

instead of

```
$j("#dynamicpageid").trigger("create")
```

Changing the .page call to trigger("create") applies the correct css rules to the header and footer and cause them to stay in place.

EDIT: Still not completely correct. Some of the pages crash if they aren't instantiated with .page() but the error is super cryptic and originates in the jquery mobile script itself.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery1830677661889931187' of undefined
```

Tracing the call-chain takes it back to a call in my code to a .trigger("create") but no the original one i'm using for the page. Weird. Trying to figure this out further.